# How do I use audio for NoInputPrompts?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to use a custom sound when Google Home receives no input from the user. But it seems to ignore any SSML data for no input reprompts converting to plain text. This is what my data looks like in my fulfilment code:

```
response.data.google = { expect_user_response: true,
                         no_input_prompts: [
                              { ssml: 'This is <say-as interpret-as="characters">SSML</say-as> with a <break time="3s"/> pause.' },
                              { ssml: '<audio src="https://...myurl.mp3" />' },
                              { ssml: '<speak><audio src="https://..myurl.mp3" /></speak>' }
                              ] }
```

The first reprompt is stripped of SSML so Google Home just says

> This is SSML with a pause

(but with no break). The second two reprompts are stripped to just silence!

Does Google not support SSML on reprompts despite the SSML property being available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to wrap the string in a `<speak>` tag to get it to register as valid SSML.

The reason the 3rd one wasn't working is that Google Home seems to override it and instead tell the user it's about to exit the skill. This may be a bug.